# How to fade in a background image change in jQUery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

So I have a div that changes its background image when a user hovers over it and also shows text hen a user hovers over the image. Is there a way so that the div's background fades into the new background on hover?

Here's my current code so far http://jsfiddle.net/nGhMz/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animate background replacement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231361/animate-background-replacement)

Answer (score 2):

You can not fade a background image, but you can position an element behind using `relative` and `absolute` positioning, as well as `z-index`.

You can then fade that element in the background.

```
var imgSrc = 'new/image.png';
container.css({backgroundImage: 'url("' + imgSrc  +'")'});
container.find('img').show().fadeOut(1000, function() { $(this).attr({src: imgSrc}) });
```

Answer (score 0):

I mis-interpreted your question the first time around...

I have re-worked your example to get the effect you are looking for. Not sure if it is the cleanest way. It uses one image as an overlay and fades it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/nGhMz/7/

Hope this helps.

Bob